# TypeError: object is not callable

Tags: python, object, closures

I have some functions that process the parameter, like :

```
def createDataModel(objectModel):
    ......
def createLayoutModel(objectModel):
    ......
def createWidgetModel(objectModel):
    ......
```

I have some xml as input files, with a specific root tag name, like ( dataModel, layout, page) then I convert them to a object model. I have a map that determines which function should process the object model

```
xsdPathsMap = {
    "dataModel": createDataModelFromXml,
    "layout": createLayoutModel,
    "page": createWidgetModelFromXml
}
```

Then I create object models from xml and assign them the function that should process them,

```
result = xsdPathsMap[xmlRootName]
# a is objectified xml
a.modelerFunction = result
```

when I want to pass the object to its closure method I got this exception:

```
a.modelerFunction(a)

TypeError: object is not callable
```

what is the problem?

and this is my Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model/xmlTranporter.py", line 204, in <module>
    a = main("main/schema")
  File "model/xmlTranporter.py", line 200, in main
    a(obj)
TypeError: 'lxml.objectify.StringElement' object is not callable
```

Comment: You aren't showing enough code to accurately diagnose the problem.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I added more information

Comment: It looks like it could work.  Can you show the complete traceback you got with the exception?

Comment: @NedBatchelder ned look, again, a question with a lot of minus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing this assignment:

```
result = xsdPathsMap[xmlRootName]
a.modelerFunction = result # this is just kind of weird
```

Either add the modeler functions to the class of `a` and just call it as a method:

```
a.createModel()
```

Or just pass a to the modeling function:

```
result(a)
```

However, this assumes that your modeling functions that you're retrieving from the map are in fact functions and not classes.

If you want to define classes that are callable that's of course fine but you need to define the  `__call__` protocol method:

```
class MyModelingFunction(object):
    ...

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """do something when I'm called"""
```

Comment: Because I had to prepare all objects then, pass them to each other and  sort them according to their priority

Answer (score 2):

The error message you get means that in `a.modelerFunction(a)`, you think you have a function, but you don't.  `a.modelerFunction` is a user-defined object, not a function.  If you post more of your code, we can figure out why.